Binding taskbar's text to parent window's view model in WinUI 3
I have a taskbar "UserHomeTaskBar" embedded in parent window "WindowUserHomeView", I want to use x:bind for binding the taskbar's date/time text to parent window's view model "WindowUserHomeViewModel", how to implement this, thanks.
taskbar.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserControl
    x:Class="Controls.Taskbar"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
  
<Border Height="60" Opacity="0.9" Background="{ThemeResource AccentAcrylicBackgroundFillColorBaseBrush}">
    <Grid Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="4" Margin="8 0">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{?Binding/x:bind TimeText?}" Style="{StaticResource TaskbarTextStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{?Binding/X:bind DateText?}" Style="{StaticResource TaskbarTextStyle}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Border>

Taskbar.xaml.cs:
namespace Controls
{
    public partial class Taskbar : UserControl
    {
        public Taskbar()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }   
    }
}

WindowUserHomeView.xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page
    x:Class="Views.UserHome.WindowUserHomeView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Views.UserHome"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:resourceModels ="using:DataAccess.Models.Resources"
    xmlns:controls="Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Border Background="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentWallpaper.Color,Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="userhomeWindow" Height="700" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentWallpaper.ImagePath,Mode=OneWay}" />

            </Grid.Background>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

         
        </Grid>
            <controls:Taskbar Grid.Row="1" x:Name="UserHomeTaskBar"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Page>

WindowUserHomeViewModel.cs:
namespace ViewModels.UserHome
{
    public class WindowUserHomeViewModel: ObservableObject, IViewModelBase
    {
        private string _timeText;
        public string TimeText
        {
            get { return _timeText; }
            set { _timeText = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _dateText;
        public string DateText
        {
            get { return _dateText; }
            set { _dateText = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public WindowUserHomeViewModel()
        {
            InitializeDateTime();
        }

    }
}


To bind the taskbar text of a parent window, we need to create a new property in the ViewModel that will hold the text to be displayed.
First, we could create a new ViewModel class called WindowUserHomeViewModel. The class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and define a new property called TaskbarText.
Next, we need to set the DataContext of the WindowUserHomeView to an instance of our new ViewModel.
And then we could use x:Bind to bind the taskbar text to the TaskbarText property.
I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1315068/taskbar-text-binding
